# Chain promises with then()

Tags: javascript, promise, browserify, when-js

I'm using the [when](https://github.com/cujojs/when) promise library to `lift()` my node style callbacks and promisify them...

```
var nodefn = require('when/node');

var one = nodefn.lift(oneFn),
    two = nodefn.lift(twoFn),
    three = nodefn.lift(threeFn);


function oneFn(callback){
    console.log('one');
    callback(null);
}

function twoFn(callback){
    console.log('two');
    callback(null);
}

function threeFn(callback){
    console.log('three');
    callback(null);
}
```

I want to call the functions in a chain, like this:

```
one().then(two).then(three).done();
```

But it gives me an error when calling the second callback function:

> Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

The error refers to the `callback` function within `twoFn(callback)`.

**What is the correct way to chain these functions together and execute one after the other?**

Comment: I haven't used `when` for a while and don't know `when.lift`, but I guess you would need to do: `one().then(function() { return two();}).then(function() {return three();}).done();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `nodefn.lift` doesn't know how many parameters the function has (zero), so it just takes the appearing arguments and appends its callback to them. In a `then` chain every callback receives the result of the previous promise (in your case: `undefined`), so your `twofn` will be called with two arguments: `undefined` and the nodeback.

So if you fix their arities, it should work:

```
Function.prototype.ofArity = function(n) {
    var fn = this, slice = Array.prototype.slice;
    return function() {
        return fn.apply(null, slice.call(arguments, 0, n));
    };
};
var one = nodefn.lift(oneFn).ofArity(0),
    two = nodefn.lift(twoFn).ofArity(0),
    three = nodefn.lift(threeFn).ofArity(0);
```

Comment: You are 100% right, I checked and those were the args passed in (`[undefined, nodeback]`). But do you have any work around or solution?

Comment: What bugs me a bit that your promises actually resolve with `null` not `undefined`. I wonder whether `when` mixes those up.

Comment: Thanks for the help, please let me know what you think of my answer.

Comment: Really? On the function prototype?

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum: Sure, I like it :-) Of course it's trivial to change to `function ofArity(fn, n) {…`

Answer (score 0):

Based on @Bergi's answer, I wrote this function:

```
function nodeLift(fn){
    return function(){
        var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 0, fn.length - 1),
            lifted = nodefn.lift(fn);

        return lifted.apply(null, args);
    };
}
```

Comment: I think you should use `nodefn.apply` directly, or otherwise put `var lifted = …` above the `return function(){`

Comment: Also note that this function is clever, but it's *too* clever for functions that have optional parameters. Proceed with care :-)